# Finding variable in PSP variable container

Tags: labview

So I have a variable containter and I'm trying to obtain a variable from it so I'm using the search variable container function and then indexing the first element in the returned array.
[image: My attempt]

I'm guessing the problem comes from the fact that I have not wired up the class terminal on the search variable container function.

The picture bellow shows them wiring PSP Variable to this terminal, this is from [Reading and Writing Shared Variables Programmatically](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvconcepts/sv_usingdynvarapi/):
[image]

Which palette would I find this under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the connector and select "Create" -> "Constant".

This create a class constant, and select the class by clicking on it and navigate in the menu to "PSP variable".